# Lenovo Z500 laptop screen goes dim after pressing F11

Tags: linux, linux-mint, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-geforce, brightness

The screen brightness changed from normal to very low right after I pressed F11. Prior to pressing it, I was already unable to adjust the screen brightness as I was using linux mint - which seems to have frequent problems with brightness already.

I’ve tried to change the graphical driver from the open source noveau into nvidia and intel (hybrid), installed and used xbacklight, pressed F11 and F12 again, but nothing changed. I’m not sure if this is related to the graphical driver or the laptop itself too.

The brightness seems to remain very low even after booting into my mint USB so the laptop itself is likely to be the cause from my deduction.

Comment: Boot from a bootable USB key and see what the brightness level is.

Comment: The brightness is still low as stated above.

Comment: If brightness is low after booting from a USB key, then there is a hardware issue with your laptop